# My boss is complaining about my personal calls

Tags: communication

I have a new boss last week in same organization.

My family called me. After some time he told me 'tell your family when you're in the office to call a lot less'. I told him don't go into personal matters, my family needed to talk to me on urgency, my 2 year old fell down from bed so my wife called. In high pitch in front of people, he said  'Phone calls records I will take out'.

How can one boss talk like this? What should I do? Tomorrow morning I have to do something. Saturday and Sunday me and my family were tensed.

Comment: Im a bit uncertain what you are asking. Did your boss ask you to take fewer personal calls at work? Was this your personal phone or work phone? Did you explain to him that it was an urgent matter? What are phone call records? transcripts? the number of calls? when you did or didn't take such calls?

Comment: Just asking boss told don't take more calls from your family..

Comment: What phone records? Was it your phone or theirs? Did you explain the reason for the urgency?

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace. You might want to consider editing your question to express things more clearly. I've not downvoted myself, but others will.

Comment: I believe you're not a native English speaker. What would the output look like if you went to https://translate.google.com/, typed what you would have written for your question in the input box, and set the translate box to English?

Comment: Was this the first personal call you received at work? How many personal calls do you receive each week? Are they really all emergencies?

Answer (score 9):

Putting it bluntly: when you're at work, you're there to work, not to talk to your family. If there's an emergency, take the call *quietly* and *professionally* so as not to disturb your co-workers, then make a decision as to whether you need to ask your boss for emergency time off. Unless your baby is actually injured, you don't need to discuss them falling out of bed in the office.

Your boss is giving you a very strong hint that you are spending too much time on personal matters in work time. Take that hint or you may discover more serious consequences down the line.

Comment: It's not yet clear that the OP has received more than one personal call - in which case,  the boss is massively overreacting.

Answer (score 1):

The personal phone call policy for each company is different, but most companies I know about have fairly broad latitude given to managers. If the company has a union, they'll have something to say on this topic also, but it is possible that it'll be said in the company's policy.

When you have a family, it's important to find out the company policy and your boss' policy. It may be helpful to communicate your situation at home to your boss, but it's best to do that when they're not upset. It's always a good idea to track exactly how much time you're spending on personal calls. If your employer were lax, you maybe could get away with just noting how long each call was and keeping track mentally. But this guy isn't, so I'd recommend recording a start and stop time for each personal call you get or make at work.

That having been said, that's just useful for next time. You have this time to worry about. But I don't think we have enough information to do that, and I'm not just talking The Workplace SE, but you, too.

Assuming your new boss is not new to the company, there are people around who know more about him and his history with employees taking personal phone calls. Behavior like this doesn't just come out of nowhere. As opportunity permits in the course of your job, or while on breaks, talk with people and ask them about it. As you get more of an understanding of what's gone on before between him and the people who report to him, you may get a better understanding of either how to convince him that you're not a problem, how to not be what he considers a problem, or how urgently you need to find a new job.

That having been said, it would be a really good idea to keep personal calls at work to a minimum until you have a better idea of what the exact rules are. As Philip Kendall said, when you really need to take a personal phone call at work, be quiet and professional about it, and keep it as short as feasible.

One thing I have found with new bosses who seem initially to be a major problem is that they're people too, and they have their own concerns and reasons for them. Sometimes talking with them about their concerns can lead to finding a path that will work for both of you. But don't try to force a conversation. That's generally a good idea at work with people who don't work for you, but it goes double with anyone in your management chain.

Maybe he'd appreciate it if you put in extra time to compensate for any time you spent on the phone. Of course, it's a good idea to determine if that is even possible before suggesting it to him. When I worked in a union shop with a physical punch clock, suggesting such a thing would immediately get people on the union steward's bad list, in addition to annoying whomever they suggested it to. At another employer, making that suggestion and then sticking to it was an effective way to get the boss to ease up on me.